# Like Button in Django

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-rest-framework

What is the preferred method of implementing like button functionality in Django:

- Using only Jquery and AJAX OR
- Django REST Framework along with a short AJAX code?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a website (SSR) no need to add DRF just for that, add a single view with an endpoint for likes `/posts/:id/likes/` `POST` for example and call it via AJAX.